# how to use cesium-navigation-development

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, terriajs

I went through the introduction, but I still cannot load this widget. Could someone give me a more specific introduction? If there is a video would be better!!!

[This is the cesium-navigation-development github](https://github.com/alberto-acevedo/cesium-navigation)

Thank you so much!!!